# One NodeJs instance or multiple, in a single core VPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, scaling, vps

I'm on confusion about this.

Let's assume I have a 1 core VPS, and I have a Nodejs server running.
Now, I launch another Nodejs instance and a load balancer to distribute requests (on the same VPS).

Will the performance increase because I will have 2 Nodejs servers sharing the work?

Or It will decrease because 1 node is already enough to handle all the requests so adding another one now plus the load balancer will just consume more of the VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create more instances than the number of CPUs, while there is an active process running on one instance, the other instances will compete for CPU to satisfy any incoming request and that will lead so using more CPU than saving time. Although negligible, having the same number of instances as cores will have better performance.